# Change column name with a .0 in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe with columns as Country, 2015.0,2016.0,2017.0 these are suppose to be years. But the column name has .0 in it. I tried to rename them but rename is not working. I am not able to remove the .0 at the end.
Any suggestions.

Comment: `dataframe.columns = ['Country', '2015', '2016', '2017']` doesn't work?

Comment: This will work but I have last 50 years of data, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `dflst = dataframe.columns.tolist()` will get you a list of columns, you could do something like `dflist.pop('Country')`, `dflst = ['Country'] + list(map(int, dflist))` and then put them back with `dataframe.columns = dflst`. Just make sure your columns are lined up right afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

#### `rename`

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return int(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        return x

df.rename(columns=f)
```